# fetch latest messages from kafka on http request

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using kafka-node client to make a restify api which when called returns the latest messages as response. I have achieved some success using the code below.

```
var consumerOptions = {
    groupId: 'ExampleTestGroup',
    fetchMaxWaitMs:500,
    fromOffset: 'latest' // equivalent of auto.offset.reset valid values are 'none', 'latest', 'earliest'
};
consumerStream=new ConsumerStream(client,[{topic:'topic1'},{topic:'topic2'}],{fromOffset:'lates',fecthMaxWaitMs:500});
consumerStream.on('error',(err)=>{
    console.log('err',err);
});
consumerStream.pipe(Stringify()).pipe(res);
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('100 ms are up');
    res.end();
    next();
},1000);
```

I have to use a time out in case there aren't enough messages on the topics and the response is returned. This works fine but only on the first request as, I assume, the offset is committed when the new request comes and it doesn't fetch any messages due to that.